# bash: changing column fields by current number of occurence/running number

Tags: string, bash, duplicates

I got stuck with a rather simple task (which is even more frustrating ;-) ):
I have a column like this:

```
>foo111_bar37
>foo111_bar38
>foo111_bar40
>foo111_bar40
>foo111_bar41
>foo111_bar42
>foo111_bar49
>foo111_bar49
>foo111_bar49
...
```

and I would like to either modify this column or get a new column, that includes the current count of the same string

```
>foo111_bar37x1
>foo111_bar38x1
>foo111_bar40x1
>foo111_bar40x2
>foo111_bar41x1
>foo111_bar42x1
>foo111_bar49x1
>foo111_bar49x2
>foo111_bar49x3
...
```

goal is that the line becomes unique and still contains the original information. 
I found out how to adress the column with awk and change strings in general (e.g. always appending "x1"), but not how to do this with number-specific changes. 
Most people seem to want to get rid of their duplicates or count the total number of duplicates, this is not helping me here.

BTW: I'm using the MobaXterm bash environment on Windows

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk, do you have it available:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++;print $1 "x" a[$1]}' file
>foo111_bar37x1
>foo111_bar38x1
>foo111_bar40x1
>foo111_bar40x2
>foo111_bar41x1
>foo111_bar42x1
>foo111_bar49x1
>foo111_bar49x2
>foo111_bar49x3
```

Explained:

```
$ awk ' {
   a[$1]++             # store to hash a using first field as key. ++ increases
                       # its value by 1 on each iteration for each $1
   print $1 "x" a[$1]  # output $1, "x" and current value of a[$1]
}' file
```

Comment: perfect, so easy...could you give me a hint on the "++"?

Comment: Updated brief explanation to solution.

Answer (score 1):

A little more shorter solution(keeping the concept same) than great answer of James Brown sir.

```
awk '{print $0"x"++array[$0]}'  Input_file
```

**Explanation:** So print keyword will print the lines in awk, so here I am printing the current line by $0 then printing string x and then printing the array named array whose index is $0 only, ++array[$0] means first it will increment the value of that array's index then it will print it.

Let's say (foo111_bar40) came one time so it will be having index inside array and it's value will be 1 so next time array sees this index is already present in array so it simply increments it by 1 and prints it then.